# customizing simple membership to use existing tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, roles, simplemembership

I have a User table in my repository pattern database and I am looking to connect the Roles. What is the best way to customize simple membership?

Answer (score 1):

Read the following MSDN articles:

[Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Implementing a Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

and the following CodeProject article:

[Custom MembershipProvider and RoleProvider Implementations that use Web Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13032/Custom-MembershipProvider-and-RoleProvider-Impleme)

Answer (score 1):

You should set your configuration in `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs` file located into the `Filters` folder of your project.

Open that file and find the following line:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", 
                                         "UserProfile", 
                                         "UserId", 
                                         "UserName", 
                                         autoCreateTables: true);
```

Now, you just need to put your connection string to your database(must be declared into web.config) into the first parameter, table name into the second parameter, UserId column name into the 3th param. and UserName column name into the 4th param.

About the last param, if you set it to true, if simple membership doesn't find any of the required table into your database, it'll create them.

However, I recommend you that you use separate tables for simple membership and let SM create its own tables. After that, you can add all your existing users to the SM tables by a block of code like the following, once for ever:

```
var oldUsers = db.Users.ToList();

foreach (User u in oldUsers)
{
    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(u.UserName, u.Password);
}
```

And after that, you haven't problems with the membership and authorization jobs any more...

Comment: What is the UsersContext? Can I replace this with my own Context that has been created for the application and contains the custom user table?

Comment: @Jay - Where you find it?

Comment: My context is contained within a Data library called Project.Data, I have included this as a reference to my project instead of Project.Models default that was there from the blank project initializer